# SharePoint training options

Tags: javascript, jsom, bcs, training

I'm looking for training in the SharePoint 2013/2016/2019 on-premises sphere with specific concentration on BCS solutions developed using JSOM and REST models.

Does anyone have a recommendation they can provide?  My company is looking to expend some EOY money.  Thanks.

Comment: We are running training sessions now but they are very high-level. Pluralsight has great courses so does https://www.edx.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are many training courses available in pluralsight, lynda.com and udemy.com. Pluralsight has large volume of course for different types of users like Beginner, Intermediate and Advanced. I think you can first start with Pluralsight.